# Problem with state change using useState in if else statement

Tags: if-statement, react-hooks, use-state

I got some issue with useState and "if else" statement. I wanted to change displayed text with a click.
When I checking if counter icrement is working, it works, but when I add setText in "if else" statement there is a problem and just doesnt work properly. Icnrement strats to work strange when clicking and change a text is just imposible. Even in console increment looks wrong. Can someone help what I am doing wrong?

```
    let counter = 0;
    const [txt, setTxt] = useState("Text1");
    
      const handleClick = (e) => {
        if (
          e.target.classList.contains("fa-angle-right") || e.target.classList.contains("fa-angle-left")
        ) {e.target.classList.contains("fa-angle-right") ? counter++ : counter--;
    
          if (counter === 1) {
            console.log(counter);
            setTxt("Text2");
          } else if (counter === 2) {
            console.log(counter);
            setTxt("Txt3")
          } else if (counter > 2) {
            counter = 0;
            console.log(counter);
            setTxt("Text1");
          } else if (counter < 0) {
            counter = 2;
            console.log(counter);
            setTxt("Text3");
          } else if (counter === 0) {
            console.log(counter);
            setTxt("Txt1");
          }
        }
      };
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time `setTxt('...')` is executed, the component is re-rendered and the function executes again, so counter gets the value of 0.
If you want to preserve the value of your counter between renders, put it as a new state ( const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0) )

Comment: I tried again and I have just put let counter outside the component and it works perfectly. :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, @AdriánFernándezMartínez I did that way and its close. Just after first clik, in a first "if" (if (counter === 1)) console shows 0 and i have to click twice to chage it and change Txt (but is should be 1 after setCounter(counter + 1)). Next, in a third "if" (else if (counter > 2)) console shows 3 and again I need to click twice to change Txt (after 1st click its 0 and after 2nd it become 1). Still need help.

```
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    const [txt, setTxt] = useState("Text1");

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    if (
      e.target.classList.contains("fa-angle-right") ||
      e.target.classList.contains("fa-angle-left")
    ) {
      e.target.classList.contains("fa-angle-right")
        ? setCounter(counter + 1)
        : setCounter(counter + 1);
      console.log(counter);
      if (counter === 1) {
        console.log(counter);
        setTxt("Text2");
      } else if (counter === 2) {
        console.log(counter);
        setTxt("Text3");
      } else if (counter > 2) {
        setCounter(0);
        console.log(counter);
        setTxt("Text1");
      } else if (counter < 0) {
        setCounter(2);
        console.log(counter);
        setTxt("Text3");
      } else if (counter === 0) {
        console.log(counter);
        setTxt("Text1");
      }
    }
    
  };
```

Comment: looks like you forgot to decrease your counter on a left angle

Comment: I know, should be: e.target.classList.contains("fa-angle-right")
        ? setCounter(counter + 1)
        : setCounter(counter - 1); mistake when pasting and editing code here :)